# C++ Visual Studio 2010 Express can't add item?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

For some reason when I start a new project in Visual Studio 2010 Express, I can't add a new item. There's not even a choice for it in the projects menu anymore, it only says rescan solution. It was working fine and all of a sudden did this and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This happened to me but it was because I was running the program in debug. I stopped it then I was able to add files

Answer (score 3):

In the solution explorer, make sure you have the project selected.  It sounds like you have the solution selected instead.

Correct:

[image]

Not correct:

[image]

Comment: Ah that worked thank you! That's weird I wonder why it did that it never did that before.